# Taskbar Pinned Icons - Change Tooltip

Tags: taskbar, icons, tooltip

I'm looking to change the tooltip for when icons are hovered over for opened programs on the taskbar.

Is it possible / how, do I go about making them say a custom text per window open, in a white dialog that is a good size to clearly read?

Kind regards,